# how to retrieve weather conditions and bit modifier for each day of the month?

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I currently working on a report summary for a campaign in Google Adwords and I,ve managed quite easily to retrieve informations such as number of clicks, ctr, etc.

But now I'm trying to get the weather conditions associated to the campaigns (Sunny or Rainy) and the mid modifiers or bid adjustments corresponding to the weather changes.

I've found a link on Google Developpers that offers relevant informations but the code examples are in Java, not JavaScript.

It seems hard to find informations related to this subject.

Does anyone know anything about this topic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a link within the Google Developers websites that will give you the scripts to conduct weather-based campaign management of your adWords campaign. Of course you need to have an adWords account set up. If you go to [this](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/weather-based-campaign-management) link, you will see the scripts and step by step directions provided for you.

An overview of the steps that you need to follow are this: (see the link provided for more detailed instructions)

> 1. Register for an API key at http://openweathermap.org/appid.
> 2. Make a copy of the template spreadsheet and edit your campaign and weather rules.
> 3. Create a new script with the source code below. (source code is provided in the original link of this answer).
> 4. Update the OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY and SPREADSHEET_URL variables in the script.
> 5. Schedule to run as required.

Comment: Thank you Kleigh for the links and the steps to follow. But I actually already have the spreadsheets and scripts running. The only thing I need is the weather and the bid adjustments.